# Running newusers util in cron to batch create users does not run

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cron, sudo, root

I'm attempting to batch create some users from a file using the `newusers` util on ubuntu 18.

When running in cron as the root user, nothing happens. When I run the command manually, it works as expected and creates the users in the file. Heres my crontab, running every minute to test:

```sh
*/1 * * * * newusers /tmp/ftp_users.txt
```

Running it manually like this is fine `newusers /tmp/ftp_users.txt`.

I have no idea what I'm missing to get this command to run in cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the full path in *cronjobs*. So find out the full path to news users (/bin/newusers/) or whatever it is, and place that in your cronjob. You can find the full path by typing

```
which newusers
```

Comment: this was the issue added PATH var to crontab

Answer (score 0):

Check the mail cron sends to root containing the console output of your command.
This will tell you what went wrong.